# Reducing instructions in while loop

Tags: riscv

So I have this piece of code:

```
i=0; while(arr[i] != value) { i = i+1; }
```

and I want to write it in Assembly.

Suppose the register x20 holds the variable i, register x21 the variable value and register x22 the address of the array. Also for simplicity there is no need to check whether the value is inside the array.

The code is:

```
    add x22, x0, x0 # i =0

loop: Condition code # Retrieving arr[i] and storing it into register x10

    beq x10, x21, exit # Comparing arr[i] to value

    addi x22, x22, 1 # i = i+1

j loop.

exit: ...
```

Is it possible for this code to be reduced ?

Comment: You are missing a load, `lw`, inside the loop, so, never fetching `a[i]`.

Comment: "Also for simplicity there is no need to check whether the value is inside the array."  What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  We rearrange the loop to exit at the bottom, with a conditional branch:

```
    add x22, x0, x0 # i =0
    j loopStart
loop: Condition code # Retrieving arr[i] and storing it into register x10
    addi x22, x22, 1 # i = i+1
loopStart:
    sll x11, x22, 2
    add x11, x22, x11
    lw x10, 0(x11)
    bne x10, x21, loop # Comparing arr[i] to value

exit: ...
```

Though this is the same number of instructions, one — the unconditional branch — is no longer inside the loop.

---

Next, we can transform the loop to using pointers as follows:

```
p=arr; 
while (*p != value) p++; 
i=p-arr;
```

This will remove the indexing computation inside the loop.